# Autoconnect headless Pi to Wifi

Tags: networking, wifi, ssh

I want my Pi B+ running Raspbian to auto connect to Wifi and startup SSH, but I'm doing something wrong. I created file named ssh in /boot/, and configured interfaces and wpa_supplicant as in guides from the net.

/etc/network/interfaces:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp
```

wpa_supplicant.conf:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
ssid="Keenetic-3401"
psk="secretpass"
proto=RSN
key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
pairwise=CCMP
auth_alg=OPEN
}
```

But Pi just doesn't connect. What can I do about it? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What OS? Put the interfaces file back to original.

Comment: you need a `country=` entry in `wpa_supplicant.conf`

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer was to add `country=RU` to`wpa_supplicant.conf` so that the file ends up like this:

```
country=RU
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="Keenetic-3401"
    psk="secretpass"
    proto=RSN
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    pairwise=CCMP
    auth_alg=OPEN
}
```